# New to C++ Looking for help revising a program by using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, if-statement, project

I'm not expecting anyone to just hand me the answer, but I am looking for some guidance. For my C++ class we wrote a program last week where we had 5 judges each had a score that the user had to put in, then we needed to find the average without the highest and lowest score being used. I did this using loops and a lot of if statements.

Now my teacher asked us to go back and use arrays, and said we should be able to just modify the original code a bit, but to now have it so there can be 5 to 20 judges, the user should be able to input that number in. I'm just having a hard time figuring out which spots could be replaced with arrays.

I already have it where a person can put in the amount of judges, but I'm not sure how to put that in an array either, so judges is an unused variable at the moment.This is what my code looks like right now. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Function prototypes

void getJudgeData(double &x);

double findLowest(double ,double ,double ,double,double);

double findHighest(double,double,double,double,double);

void calcAverage(double,double,double,double,double);

double judges;
//Program begins with a main function

int main()    
{   
    //Declare variables

    double judgeScore1,judgeScore2,judgeScore3;

    double judgeScore4,judgeScore5;

    cout<<"Scores given by all five judges: \n\n";

    //Function calls to get each judge data
    cout<< "How many Judges are there? (Must be 5 to 20): ";
    cin>> judges;

    while(judges<5||judges>20){
        cout<< "Sorry there must be 5 to 20 judges\n";
        cout<< "How many Judges are there? (Must be 5 to 20): ";
        cin>> judges;

        getJudgeData(judgeScore1);

        getJudgeData(judgeScore2);

        getJudgeData(judgeScore3);

        getJudgeData(judgeScore4);

        getJudgeData(judgeScore5);

        //Function call to obtain average

        calcAverage(judgeScore1,judgeScore2,judgeScore3,

        judgeScore4,judgeScore5);

        //Pause the system for a while    
    }
}
//Method definition of getJudgeData

void getJudgeData(double &x)    
{    
    //Prompt and read the input from the user and check //input validation

    cout<<"Enter score of a Judge (you will do this 5 times): ";

    cin>>x;

    while (x < 0 || x > 10)    
    {   
        cout<<"ERROR: Do not take judge scores lower than 0 or higher than 10.Re-enter again: ";

        cin>>x;    
    }

}

//Method definition of findLowest

double findLowest(double a,double b,double c, double d,double e)    
{    
    double lowest;

    lowest=a;

    if (b<lowest)    
        lowest=b;

    if (c<lowest)    
        lowest=c;

    if (d<lowest)    
        lowest=d;

    if (e<lowest)

    lowest=e;

    return lowest;    
}


//Method definition of findHighest

double findHighest(double a,double b,double c, double d,double e)    
{    
    double highest;

    highest=a;

    if (b>highest)

    highest=b;

    if (c>highest)    
        highest=c;

    if (d>highest)    
        highest=d;

    if (e>highest)    
        highest=e;

    return highest;   
}




void calcAverage(double a,double b,double c,double d, double e)    
{

    //Declare variables

    double lowest;

    double highest;

    double sum;

    double average;

    //Function call to retrieve lowest score

    lowest=findLowest(a,b,c,d,e);

    //Function call to retrieve highest score

    highest=findHighest(a,b,c,d,e);

    //Calculate the total sum

    sum=a+b+c+d+e;

    //Subtract highest and lowest scores from the total

    sum=sum-highest;

    sum=sum-lowest;

    //Calculate the average of the three number after

    //dropping the highest and lowest scores

    average=sum/3;

    //Display output

    cout<<"Highest score of five numbers:"<<highest<<endl;

    cout<<"Lowest score of five numbers:"<<lowest<<endl;

    cout<<"Average when highest and lowest scores are removed: "<<average<<endl;    
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using an array to keep track of the judges score, like `double judgeScore[nbrOfJudges]`. Now you can access a judges score by `judgeScore[2]`. If you're allowed to use std::vector, I would recommend that instead of an array.

Comment: What is your question? Indent your code correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to hold the scores of the judges rather than storing them in judgeScore1, ... , judgeScore5. The size of the array should be 20, which is the maximum number of judges:

```
double judgeScore[20];
```

The variable "judges" should be declared as "int", as it is the number of judges.

The functions should accept an array of double as parameter, rather than 5 double values. So, instead of:

```
double findLowest(double ,double ,double ,double,double);
```

the function becomes:

```
double findLowest(double s[]);
```

The body of the functions should use the variable "judges" as a limit of a "for" loop in order to perform the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your functions to use arrays. For example, here's a `get_max` function for use in an array:

```
#include <iostream>

double get_max(double judge_scores[], int size)
{
    double max = judge_scores[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (judge_scores[i] > min)
        {
            max = judge_scores[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Change all of your functions like that one. I coded up your problem and here's the `main` I got:

```
int main()
{
    const int MAX_NUM_JUDGES = 20;

    // make everything in the array 0
    double judge_scores[MAX_NUM_JUDGES] = { 0 };

    // make it return the "amount" of array you need- the number of judges
    int num_judges = get_num_judges();

    // fill the array up to that "amount"
    // internally uses int get_judge_data() to get a score in the correct range
    fill_score_array(judge_scores, num_judges);

    // get the average. Internally, this
    // - computes the sum
    // - calls the max and min functions and subtracts those from the sum
    // - divides that sum by (num_judges - 2)
    // (because you're throwing away the max and min) and returns that.
    double avg = calculate_curved_average(judge_scores, num_judges);

    //print everything
    std::cout << " Highest: " << get_max(judge_scores, num_judges) << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Lowest: " << get_min(judge_scores, num_judges) << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Avg when highest and lowest scores are removed: " << avg << std::endl;

    // If you're not on Windows, don't use this :)
    system("PAUSE");
}
```